# How to make your own SDK from code files?

Tags: c++, sdk

I have programmed a game with lots of C++ code and it started to take more time then ever to compile my code.

So I thought maybe I can split the game's rendering code as it's own binary SDK.

I have used many SDKs and APIs before, But I don't know how to make my own SDK and how does it all hold up together.

Does any one know a good online tutorial or book about how to make a SDK. thanks.

Comment: Which compiler are you using and what platform(s) do you want to target?

Comment: Technically, you're asking about building separate libraries, which is a component of an SDK.  You don't need an SDK, just multiple binary targets.

Comment: You should also check how you deal with header-files. Doing it right can vastly decrease your compile time! The rule in short is: "no header-includes, in header-files!"

Comment: That's not a good rule.  A header file should just work if you include it.  I don't want to track down dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about creating libraries. You then compile your game's rendering code as it's own library file.

Here is an example of how do create and use a static library using Visual C++ : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

PS: As for increasing compilation times, consider using pre-compiled headers on your platform.